# How can I use an alias with HAVING clause?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, aggregate-functions, having

I'm trying to JPQL equivalent to the following SQL.

```sql
SELECT last_name, COUNT(1) AS c
FROM actor
GROUP BY last_name
HAVING c > 1
ORDER BY c DESC
```

I tried with the following JPQL.

```sql
SELECT e.lastName, COUNT(e.lastName) AS c
FROM Actor
GROUP BY e.lastName
HAVING c > 1
ORDER BY c DESC
```

And Hibernate generates following SQL and complains.

```sql
    select
        actor0_.last_name as col_0_0_,
        count(actor0_.last_name) as col_1_0_ 
    from
        actor actor0_ 
    group by
        actor0_.last_name 
    having
        c>=? 
    order by
        col_1_0_ DESC limit ?
```

When I changed the JPQL like this, it works.

```sql
SELECT e.lastName, COUNT(e.lastName) AS c
FROM Actor
GROUP BY e.lastName
HAVING COUNT(e.lastName) > 1
ORDER BY c DESC
```

How can I use the alias named `c` with the `HAVING` clause?

If I just can not, is the query ok? any optimal way to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPQL does not support using the alias in the `HAVING` clause, mainly because not all SQL engines support this behavior.  For example, both Oracle and Postgres would not support your first version of the query.

If you want to use pure JPQL, then just repeat the entire count expression in the `HAVING` clause.  If you really want to reuse the alias in the `HAVING` clause, then make your query a native one, and it will run without any problems assuming MySQL be the underlying database.

Comment: Thank you, sir. So, the 2nd version is the best I can do?

Comment: AFAIK with JPQL yes, the second version is the best you can do.